# Normalizing a quasi-rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

I have a rotation matrix $R$ generated after a lot of multiplications, inverting and so on. However, the outcome is not completely normalized, e.g., $R R^T \neq I$, but close. How can I fully normalize it?

Comment: If $RR^T\ne I$ it's not a rotation matrix; I can't imagine how "normalizing"" something could fix this, unless maybe for some reason having to do with exactly what $RR^T$ _is_.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of accumulated floating point errors and similar things

Comment: I think maybe the problem can be formulated differently. How can I find the rotation matrix R2, that gives outputs the closest values to the original matrix R?

Comment: Make first the columns orthogonal, then normalize columns to unit length.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Comment: If you’re trying to find a “best-fit” rotation, consider working with quaternions instead and convert to a rotation matrix at the end. This finesses the orthogonality issue and can be more stable numerically.

Comment: An easy solution is (modified) Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Numerical_stability (if your matrix is $3\times3$, you needn't worry about stability).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are *lots* of ways to orthogonalize the matrix.

One of the comments already mentioned the SVD method.
$$\eqalign{
R &= USV^T,\quad R_s &= UV^T \cr
}$$
Consider the skew and Cayley transformations of a matrix $A$:
$$\eqalign{
&{\rm skew}(A) = \tfrac{1}{2}(A-A^\dagger) \\
&{\rm cay}(A) = (I+A)^{-1}(I-A) \\
&A = {\rm cay}({\rm cay}(A))
}$$
Then another way to repair your bad $R$ matrix is the following sequence of operations
$$\eqalign{
R_c &= {\rm cay}({\rm skew}({\rm cay}(R))) \cr
}$$
You can do something similar with exponentials and logarithms.
$$\eqalign{
R_e &= \exp({\rm skew}(\log(R))) \cr
}$$
Polar decomposition offers yet another way
$$\eqalign{
R_p &= R(R^TR)^{-1/2} \cr
}$$

---

But the best method is to iterate
$$\eqalign{
R := \tfrac{3}{2}R - \tfrac{1}{2}RR^TR
}$$ until $\det(R)$ is sufficiently close to ${\large\tt 1}$,
or $\big(R-RR^TR\big)$ is close to zero.

Notice that this iteration does not require any expensive decompositions, or matrix inverses, or transcendental functions. It is also *quadratically* convergent, so even if you've lost half of the digits in $R$ due to rounding errors, you will gain them all back with a **single** iteration.

### Update

Yet another method, with a fairly low operation count
$$R_a = {\rm cay}\bigg(\frac{R^T-R}{1+{\rm Tr}(R)}\bigg)$$